# Diameters of random bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, random-matrices, bipartite-graphs

Given two partite sets of vertices $U$ and $V$ of size $n$. Each vertex in $U$ uniformly randomly selects $K$ ($K$ is a constant and $K\ll n$) vertices in $V$ without replacement and connects a bidirectional edge to each of the vertices it selects. My question is, what is the expected diameter of the bipartite graph generated this way? Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear, Each vertex in $U$ "Uniformly" randomly selects K vertices in $V$?

Comment: Yes! And sorry for my poor expression.

Comment: I feel like this question does not have a well-defined answer. What if the graph ends up being disconnected? You have some positive probability of a graph with infinite diameter...

Comment: This is the bipartite k-out model. 
See this book (Ch 18) for relevant material. Diameter ought to be similar to a  random regular bipartite graph...logarithmic in n

Comment: Actually, just realized if only one side chooses neighbors, then there will be isolated vertices on the other side, so koifish's concern is the correct one to have

Comment: I'm curious about the result, but you forgot to cite the book... @dbal

Comment: Thanks a lot! @dbal

Comment: whoops! this one: https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/BOOK.pdf